# Mix-up of set path: Python 2.7 and 3.5. How to set it right?

Tags: python, linux, docker

Coming back to an old problem. The cause of the problem could be the path set. This is what I get from `pprint(sys.path)`

```
import sys  
from pprint import pprint  
pprint(sys.path)  
['',  
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',  
'/usr/lib/python3.5',  
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', (comment: 2.7 appears)  
'/usr/lib/python2.7', (comment: again 2.7 appears)  
'/usr/lib/python35.zip',  
'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',  
'/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',  
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Seems like a mix-up of Python 3.5 and 2.7 in set-path. There must be something similar to message would show for 2.7 also with the same command as the above. But can not check, as $python2.7 command itself can not be executed, ended up with error message.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I am working on a Linux ubuntu 16.04, Docker container.

Comment: What is the value of `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Can you share the `Dockerfile` that built the image?  It's unusual to have more than one version of Python in a container at all.

Comment: >>> import sys     
>>> print(sys.path)      
['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',  
 '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to share the docker file. I am using docker for the first time. In the main device both 2.7 and 3.5 exists and there is no conflict.  I have tried with deleting my container. But when created a new, it gives similar problem. Refreshing is not a problem for me, as I don't have many important files there. And I can install necessary packages again. I just want a clean environment.